# Using VNC with Herra seems to require a monitor to be connected to machine?

Tags: vnc

I got VNC to fire up (using X11VNCServer) and I can connect ok.

HOWEVER

If there isn't a monitor connected to the remote machine I get a white screen, that is very small.  With a monitor I get the full background, desktop, etc.  If the monitor is turned off, I get the white screen as well (I still can get to Applications, but the screen is fairly small and not all that usable)

Am I missing something?  Or is this the expected behavior?  I have read that it's tricky to get VNC to work at all, so just trying to understand limitations.

Comment: That is the expected behavior, actually. There are a couple of things you can do about it. You can get dummy devices and there's [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=197299) (I'm positive there are better links if you start digging into the keywords and doing more searching) which should be almost correct for eOS. You need to export the display and trick x11 into thinking there's a display. Once you do that, it should work just fine. I haven't had to do it, so I only sort of know about it from reading previous answers or blog posts.

Comment: FYI -- I did some digging and and didn't find a clear answer.... however, I did stumble on this : https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FLZXGJ6/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=B00FLZXGJ6&linkCode=as2&tag=bgsco-20   Which is a "fake" monitor device   I'm going to give it a try (ordered it and the 4K version) as I'd rather not go down a rabbit hole SW wise to try to configure something to work (only to have it break on next elementary OS update).  I suspect elementary team will ultimately fix this, so for now this looks like simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback which lead me in the right direction!

Comment: The dummy device is probably the easiest solution. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Also, the eOS team probably won't "ultimately fix this", as this is the expected behavior. You're using x11vnc and x11 is what controls the display output. If there's no display, x11 can't forward it with VNC. It's probably not obvious - but it's in the title - x11vnc. You could also have tried other VNC software, but frankly I don't blame you for not doing so. From my years of use, x11vnc is the most reliable method I've ever used. For my viewing client, I use RealVNC's VNCViewer. It's proprietary, but it 'just works'.

Comment: Actually I DID try about 4-5 other VNC clients and found x11vnc to be the most reliable.  RealVNC I wasn't so happy with the pricing to get direct connections.  (FYI -- I have used X since X10... so the X11 part I got, I just didn't realize there wasn't support for the elementary OS version of the desktop.  I was able to get some "blank" X screens using some.  Which would work, if I didn't want the Elementary Desktop.   And XRDP had similar issues.

Comment: Anyway, the "fake" monitor adapter came, using the 4K one I can set resolutions up to 4K so that's definitely the easiest answer.  I would hope that possibly XRDP might get better support, or a more "built in" dummy display.... that was where I was hoping Elementary dev might go.